# Checking user role via discord.js and then deleting that role on Discord and checking for it again via discord.js: deleted role still shown, why?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am checking for roles with discord bot that does this:

```
const member = await guild.members.fetch(user_id)

console.log(member._roles)
```

Roles are logged as expected, but when I delete one of them in Discord and query the bot again, it still shows exactly the same roles not recognizing that there's one less.

Same thing if I use the `roles.cache.some` method instead (even if deleted on Discord, the bot shows "user has role already")

```
if (member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'verify-test-role')) {console.log("user has role already")
```

When I restart the bot, roles are correct again. Why is that? How can I keep the bot able to track role changes?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I needed to add `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` to my client like this:

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers
    ]
});
```

Also had to enable `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers` in the Discord Developer Portal under BOT --> Privileged Gateway Intents

Now it's updating perfectly.